# Compartiendo archivo de audio en whatsapp solo transfiere el primer segundo

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp

Mi problema es el siguiente.

Genero un archivo de audio (.wav) desde mi aplicación y la comparto a traves de un intent.. pero al hacerlo via whatsapp solo se envia 1 seg de audio. Cuando lo envío via correo electronico funciona correctamente, se envía el archivo completo.

Alguna idea que puede estar fallando?

El archivo lo guardo en la carpeta "/storage/emulated/0/Download/prueba1.wav"

```
public void startShare() {
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "//prueba1.wav");
    Log.d("SHARE FILE", "File: " + f);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.setType("audio/mp3");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));

}
```

Slds.

ACTUALIZO:
No es un segundo de audio lo que envía Whatsapp, sino aproximadamente la mitad de la duración del Wav.
Creo que el problema esta en el formato de Wav que usa synthesizeToFile, ya que intente enviar el archivo generado por mi aplicación directamente desde Whatsapp con el mismo problema. En cambio cuando lo convertí a MP3 lo pude enviar sin problemas.

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, seguire investigando.

Slds.

Comment: Me parece que share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); no es necesario solo agrega el permiso.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el mime type definido para un archivo .wav :

```
share.setType("audio/wav");
```

No olvides definir el permiso:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario. Ya lo he intentado teniendo el mismo resultado. Creo que el problema no está en el codigo, porque al cargar el mismo archivo desde Whatsapp, sigue teniendo el mismo problema. Sospecho que el problema es el formato de Wav que utiliza synthesizeToFile, ya que probe convertir el mismo archivo a MP3 y volvi a intentar enviarlo desde Whatsapp y no hubo problemas.